# React Native: How can I create a binary and run it directly on iPhone?

Tags: xcode, react-native, app-store, app-store-connect, testflight

I have a bug in my React Native app that occurs on TestFlight builds but not when I run it from my computer. Is there a way to create a binary like the one that I'd push to the App Store, and then run it directly on my device so that I don't have to push it to TestFlight every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a "Release" build of your React Native app and run it on your phone by changing the scheme of the "Run" action.

First, click on your target in the Xcode header (left side of the attached image).

[image]

Scroll down and choose "Edit scheme"

Next, choose the "Run" scheme.

[image]

Then, change "Build configuration" to "Release".

Connect your phone, choose the phone as a build target and `Run` from Xcode. The version that will be run will be the same as the version that gets created when you archive and send to TestFlight.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. This build is still behaving a bit differently than the TestFlight build; I know you said they'd be the same, but can you think of any differences there might be?

Comment: Not without more details -- "behaving differently" is pretty vague.

Answer (score 0):

I think the closet thing you can do is

**1)** Connect your phone with a usb to your computer

**2)** You have to press trust device

**3)** Open up the file `ios/__YOUR_PROJECT_NAME_.xcworkspace`

**4)** On the top you will something like this below. Click where it says "iPhone 12 Pro Max" and choose your phone out of the options
[image]

**5)** Finally press the arrow to run